# Camunda does not save filter with candidate group and candidate user

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

Camunda just saves the candidate user and discards the candidate group.

Am I doing something wrong?

[trying to save two criteria: candidate group and user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY6Bs.png)

[save only one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3aPj.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I understand your issue is that the candidate group filter value does not get saved when you save the filter. Sorry, I cannot reproduce this on 7.17.0. Both filter criteria get saved when i save such a  filter. Try on 7.17.0? Or did I misunderstand the issue?

Comment: cliff2310 and community - I have to disagree with your comments. The wording is not brilliant, but For someone who knows Camunda I believe the question is sufficiently clear.

Comment: try to consult the filter to make sure your criteria are really saved @rob2universe